# Retaining/Show the name of transferred files in Python GUI on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, file-transfer

I am writing a program in python on Ubuntu to get files transfer from Remote Linux machine to My Host Ubuntu machine and both machines are directly connected to each other through CAT5 cable. My Program successful get files from other Linux machine and show number of file transferred.
But I want to add a list of transferred files from remote linux machine to host machine with number of  transferred files.

Can you please help me to improve my coding to get the required result.

```
import io,sys,os,subprocess
import Tkinter,ttk 
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

def transFile():
    num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path)if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
    previous =num_files                    # Count Number of Files before Transferred New Files
    ip ="192.168.2.34"
    os.system("rsync -rav pi@"+ip+":python ~/") # Command To transfer Files
    num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path)if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
    present = num_files-previous 
    tkMessageBox.showinfo (" File Transfer", 'Number of Files Transfer is '+ str(present)+ '!')

def exitFiles():
    root.quit()

root = Tk()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="200 200 200 200")
mainframe.grid()

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="File Transfer", command=transFile).grid (column=10, row=3)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Exit",          command=exitFiles).grid (column=95, row=3)

global process
path = os.path.expanduser("~/python")           # Define path To play, delete, or rename video 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since there is no direct problem this might be better suited for code review or another stack exchange site.

Comment: @EWit can you please guide me where should I asked this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added last five lines which will show you all the files in the folder, might be u will get ur required answer after more parsing

```
def transFile():
    num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path)if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
    previous =num_files                    # Count Number of Files before Transferred New Files
ip ="192.168.2.34"
os.system("rsync -rav pi@"+ip+":python ~/") # Command To transfer Files
num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path)if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
present = num_files-previous 
tkMessageBox.showinfo (" File Transfer", 'Number of Files Transfer is '+ str(present)+ '!')    
a=0
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch(file, '*.*'):
        a +=1
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text=file).grid(row=4+a, column=10)
```

Comment: is that possible, if I can just view newly transferred file